# iptable rule to allow ftp connections between two networks

Tags: linux, networking, ftp, iptables

I have two machines, machine1 is configured with 192.168.1.0/24 network and machine2 with 10.10.0.0/24 network.

I have dropped the communication between the two networks with `iptables -P FORWARD DROP`. But I want to allow ftp connections to and from the machine2 in active mode.

Im doing the rule as below to achieve this, but when I test its not working.

```
iptables –A FORWARD –s 192.168.1.0/24 –d 10.10.0.1 –p tcp –-dport 20:21 –m state -–state NEW,ESTABLISHED –j ACCEPT
iptables –A FORWARD –d 10.10.0.1 –s 192.168.1.0/24 –p tcp –-dport 20:21 –m state –-state NEW,ESTABLISHED –j ACCEPT
```

Can you hive some help to understand why it isn´t working?

Comment: Similar question answered on another SE site. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93554/iptables-to-allow-incoming-ftp

Answer (score 1):

First off; if your drop rule is first in the chain, nothing will get to your next rules - you need to have that rule after the allow rules.

It's a two way communication, so you need to have rules in both directions. Something like this, repeated for port 20, should work, if your drop rule comes after them.

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You need to have the forward rules, which will vary based on your net topology; if these are being applied on a router, which isn't clear to me from your description, the static route needs to be set there as you apparently did. Adjust the state conditions as needed (if that doesn't make sense let me know).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Yes, i have a router where Im applying the rules.  But with your rule the router is accepting all communications from any source and for any destionation right? But I would like to allow just the ftp communications to and from the  machine2 in active mode.

Comment: The drop rule comes next.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables : a packet traverses a chain, each rule in turn is examined. If a rule does not match the packet, the packet is passed to the next rule. If a rule does match the packet, the rule takes the action indicated by the target/verdict, which may result in the packet being allowed to continue along the chain or it may not.

Comment: Not to be a pedant, but you need to read up on things before dismissing assistance.

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but the rule is not working either the drop forward command is executed after or before the rule. So the issue should be in the rule, but it seems corretly so I dont understand and ask.

Comment: Iptables has a bit of a learning curve, to put it mildly. If it isn't working I'll need more info to help. First off, is the network topology effectively these two lans, each with a dedicated router for the subnet? If not please describe it. What model routers? What OSes on the two machines? How are the two lans connected - an output on each routers lan side or wan to wan, or something remote- eg a VPN into one router?  Without considering blocking all traffic (no drop rule in place), can you communicate at all between the two machines - a ping, ssh, ftp? The more info the better.